# Why is zero-point energy idolized as a good source of energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy-conservation, vacuum

I've really only seen it in like liquid helium and I don't understand how it can hold the potential portrayed in the incredible movie by the main villian

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to asking about human perception of a natural phenomenon rather than the phenomenon itself.

Answer (score 1):

It can't.  The Incredibles, being an animated film about a family of superhumans, is not the best place to look for actual physics.